# Clarification of recursive calls in binary tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree

Could somebody provide a clarification of recursive calls for a solution to this problem:

> Given a binary tree containing digits from 0-9 only, each root-to-leaf
>   path could represent a number. Find the total sum of all root-to-leaf
>   numbers.

For example, for this tree:

```
     1
    / \
   2   3
 /   \
4     5
```

the result should be equal to `12 + 13 + 24 + 25`

The recursive solution for this problem is:

```
public int sum(TreeNode root) {
  return helper(root, 0);  
}

private int helper(TreeNode node, int sum){
  if(node == null) return 0;
  sum = sum * 10 + node.val;
  if(node.left == null && node.right == null) return sum;
  return helper(node.left, sum) + helper(node.right, sum);
}
```

I am trying to follow all recursive calls of method `helper` and figure out sum value at every step.

For example, on the first step variable `sum` equals to 0*10 + 1 = 1. Then we call `helper(node.left, 1)` and `sum` on that step equals to `1 * 10 + 2 = 12`. Then we call `helper(node.left, 12)` and `sum` on that step equals to `12 * 10 + 4 = 124`, which is obviously not correct, since the `sum` should be `24`.

Could anybody explain what is wrong in my approach?

Comment: The 'solution' does not really match the problem. `24` is not a root-to-leaf number, but `124` is.

Comment: The root-to-leaf paths also spell 124 and 125, both your actual and expected outcomes are off.

Comment: And what about the `node.left == null || node.right == null` case?

Comment: @alain Does result equal to 124+125+13?

Comment: I would say yes.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Isn't this case covered by `if(node == null) return 0`

Comment: Yes, and so could (should) the `&&` case be.

Comment: According to my understanding the number has to be a 2 digit number and also it is formed as rootvalue at ten's place and left child or right child at ones place , Am I correct about this @rset_d ?

Comment: @zenwraight Actually, the numbers are formed by the nodes if going from the root to every leaf. In this example, those numbers are 124, 125 and 13

Answer (score 0):

Try this (but I also prefer 124 + 125 + 13 as result):

```
public int sum(TreeNode root) {
      if (root == null) return 0;
      return sum(root, 0);
}

private int sum(TreeNode node, int parentValue){
      if(node == null) return 0;
      return sum(node.left, node.val) + sum(node.right, node.val) + parentValue * 10 + node.val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are missing the intermediate nodes data and 2 digit data restriction.

Remove 'if(node.left == null && node.right == null) return sum;', send only parent node value to recursive call and add current node data.

Solution of DoctorLOL is almost correct, you may want to add ignoring the root node data code to it. Following code might help.

```
public int sum(TreeNode root) {
  return helper(root, -1);
}

private int helper(TreeNode node, int parentValue){
  if(node == null) return 0;
  if (parentValue != -1)
    return helper(node.left, node.val) + helper(node.right, node.val) + parentValue * 10 + node.val;
  else
    return helper(node.left, node.val) + helper(node.right, node.val)
}
```

Hope it helps!